# How do I show full dates in Google Gantt Charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, date-formatting, gantt-chart

I am using Google Gantt Charts to visualize a schedule of classes. On hover, I currently see "name: month yyyy - month yyyy." My goal is to also see the specific date of the month, so that it would look like "name: month dd yyyy - month yyyy" or "dd mm yyyy - dd mm yyyy".

I have class data stored in a MySQL table, which I am adding to the chart data table with an ajax request.

[Here is the visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC2SU.png)

[Here is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4e68.png)

Here is my javascript code:

```js
function drawChart() {

  var calendarTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  calendarTable.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  calendarTable.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  calendarTable.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  calendarTable.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  calendarTable.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  calendarTable.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  calendarTable.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  calendarTable.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  var options = {
    height: 800,
    gantt: {
      trackHeight: 30,
      sortTasks: true,
      percentEnabled: true
    }
  };

  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  var queryString;
  if (currentUrl.includes("SAT")) {
    queryString = "/calendars.json?campus=sat";
  } else if (currentUrl.includes("DAL")) {
    queryString = "/calendars.json?campus=dal";
  } else if (currentUrl.includes("HOU")) {
    queryString = "/calendars.json?campus=hou";
  } else if (currentUrl.includes("java")) {
    queryString = "/calendars.json?programType=full-stack+web+dev+-+java";
  } else if (currentUrl.includes("science")) {
    queryString = "/calendars.json?programType=data+science";
  } else {
    queryString = "/calendars.json";
  }

  console.log(queryString);

  $.ajax({
    url: queryString,
    dataType: "JSON",
  }).done(function(data) {

    var calendarArray = [];
    //                console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(acalendar) {
      var calendarItem = [acalendar.id.toString(), acalendar.name, acalendar.campus + ' ' + acalendar.programType, new Date(acalendar.startDate), new Date(acalendar.gradDate), null, null, null];
      calendarArray.push(calendarItem);
    });
    calendarTable.addRows(calendarArray);
    var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(calendarTable, options);
    console.log(calendarArray);

  });
}
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['gantt']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: unfortunately, the Gantt chart does not allow customizing the tooltip. when displaying the tooltip, the chart calculates the duration in order to determine what should be displayed. for instance, if it were only a few days, it would display -- MMM dd - dd, yyyy -- you can see this at work in their [simple example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#a-simple-example)...